# Get FaceModel - Azure Kinect

Tags: azurekinect

I'm working with the new Azure Kinect and it's totally new for me.
Is this new Azure Kinect have something like Kinect V2 FaceModel? I'm looking it but I didn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no FaceModel part of Azure Kinect DK, but you may want to look into [Azure Vision service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/) that works with Azure Kinect DK.